# how to use "shipped" in kernel module makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I want to generate a .ko file by linking a built object file .. I read about shipped in "kbuild" system but not enough details.

Please help.

Comment: Can you explain more on what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The Kbuild system deletes all object files (`*.o`) upon the `make clean` command. Any external object files will also get deleted unless their extension is changed form `.o` to `.o_shipped` to preserve them.

The following example `Makefile` demonstrates how to use `_shipped` to link an object file `8123_bin.o_shipped` within the module `8123.ko` :

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# kbuild part of makefile
obj-m  := 8123.o
8123-y := 8123_if.o 8123_pci.o 8123_bin.o

else
# normal makefile
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

# Module specific targets
genbin:
        echo "X" > 8123_bin.o_shipped
endif
```

Basically a `.o_shipped` file is the same as an `.o` file except that the Kbuild system understands that it is a binary blob which is provided as-is and whose source is NOT available in the kernel/module source directories. Hence the `*.o_shipped` binary blobs will be retained even when the source is cleaned.

More details can be found in **[Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)**